# Issues with Pipenv on git-bash.exe

Tags: python, django, pip, git-bash, pipenv

**OS Info:**

```
OS: Windows 10 
Version: 1909
Build: 18363.476
```

**Python Info:**

```
Python: v3.8.0 
Python path: C:\Python\38
Pip: v
Pip Path: C:\Python\38\Scripts
```

**Terminal:**

```
shell: bash.exe (git-bash)
version: 2.24.0.2-64-bit
```

**Issue:** 
Trying to initiate dependency management running on bash.exe (git-bash) and end up with some issues...

```sh
$ pipenv shell                                                                                       
Warning: Python 2.7 was not found on your system…
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
  $ pipenv --python path\to\python
```

Trying to install another package such as `pipenv install django` would give me same error.

I am not sure what's exactly error was and I cannot find any solution after searching around answers for 2 days.

**What have I done?**

I have downloaded python3.8 (Windows x86-64 executable installer for win 64 AMD64/EM64T/x64) from this site https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/.

Installed python3.8 following my customized path `C:\Python\38` and made sure **"Add Python3.8 to PATH"** is checked before begin installing.

After completed install python in my system, I have installed pipenv following

```
pip install pipenv
```

Installation was success after confirmed with `pipfreeze`

```
pip freeze
astroid==2.3.3
autopep8==1.4.4    
certifi==2019.11.28
colorama==0.4.1
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
pipenv==2018.11.26
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pylint==2.4.3
six==1.13.0
virtualenv==16.7.8
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3
wrapt==1.11.2
```

and there's `pipenv.py` inside C:\Python\38\Scripts.

What exactly is my issue, and is there a way to resolve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3.
You can install with `pip3 install django`.

if you want to use `pipenv` :

```
pip install pipenv
```

Then you can go to the project directory and define the pipenv environment:

```
cd project_root
pipenv install
```

for new package installation

```
pipenv install <package>
```

to remove the package

```
pipenv uninstall <package>
```